# can I get the table name from sqlite query string?

Tags: javascript, regex, sqlite

I have a query string for select statement and I want to separate the table name from the given string using regular expression in javascript. I think when the from word is found then split the next word and return.

Sample query string

```
var query="select name,age from tbl_name where id='30'";
var query="select name,age from tbl_name;
var query="select * from tbl_name where id='30'";
```

When you match with above three string it should return the table name "**tbl_name**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
"/select.*from\s+(\w+)/i"
```

See demo: [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lN7zX2/1)

In the demo I put the "g" modifier, but that is just so you can see the regex tested on all three cases. The g should not be in your final regex.

Here is an example on how to use it.

```js
    var query = [];
    query[0] = "select   name  , age from tbl_name1 where id='30'";
    query[1] = "select name,age from tbl_name2";
    query[2] = "select * from tbl_name3 where id='30'";
    var arrayLength = query.length;
    var tableName;

    for (var x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++) 
    {
      tableName = query[x].match(/select.*from\s+(\w+)/i)[1];
      document.body.innerHTML += tableName + " ";
    }
```

Comment: can you give some more details how can I use this in my code?

Comment: I added a small code, but is basically how jcubic described.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```js
var query="select * from tbl_name where id='30'";
var tableName = query.match(/from ([^ ]+)/i)[1];
document.body.innerHTML = tableName;
```